# How to view output of postdeploy script on heroku?

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I specified a postdeploy script in my app.json. The build info in the heroku web interface shows "There was an issue while running the post deploy script."

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "postdeploy": "./bin/heroku_postdeploy"
  },
```

How can I get the output / logs of my postdeploy script, to see what went wrong? `heroku logs`does not show the output.

When I run the postdeploy script via heroku CLI everything works fine.

Comment: The heroku pages say you need to contact support, to get the logs for the pr-predestroy scripts. Maybe it's the same for the postdeploy. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps#pr-predestroy-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of a failure of the dynos (in my case mixed paid and non paid dynos), the post deploy log is not displayed, although the error said the postdeploy script had an error. Heroku support figured that out. They said, they're going to make the errors and logs better in the future.

At the moment you would need to contact support. But first check, if you have your dynos configured correctly.

Comment: Support page state's postdeploy log is available from Dashboard (https://help.heroku.com/LXRRBMM3/how-do-i-view-postdeploy-script-output); however, there is no "Review app card" or "Pipeline page", at least in the free tier.